# Subtracting hours from a timestamp

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a data frame with date column as a date time format:

```
For eg: "2021-02-19T05:00:00+00:00"
```

I want to subtract some x hours from it.
How can it be done?

Comment: There are a million answers on formatting dates in Python, many even on this site. Please try to at the very least do something yourself instead of outsourcing logic to someone else

Comment: Convert that string into an actual datetime object, and then subtract timedelta hours=x from it.  What is the difficulty?

Answer (score 2):

Here you are :

```py
# 1. Import datetime
from datetime import datetime

# 2. Define function
def retrieve_hour(date_str: str, value: int):
    return datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(date_str).hour - value

# Apply to pandas.Dataframe with the value
x = <VALUE>
data[COLUMN_NAME2] = data[COLUMN_NAME1].apply(retrieve_hour, x)
```

**References**
https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/datetime.html#available-types

Comment: this doesn't work.
this return just the hour. However, I wanted the date time format as in input just subtracting the hour from that

Comment: @loyala if you want you can do `pandas.to_datetime(data[COLUMN])` to transform your column into a column of datetime object and then use `pandas.to_datetime(data[COLUMN]).dt.hour` to get the hour from your datetimes

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have this timestamp:

```
time_str = '24/7/2021 11:13:08.230010'
```

It follows this format:

```
date_format_str = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f'
```

You have to create a datetime object:

```
given_time = datetime.strptime(time_str, date_format_str)
```

then you just subtract n. ex n=4

```
n = 4
final_time = given_time - timedelta(hours=n)
```

And at then end you return to the initial format

```
final_time_str = final_time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Comment: The answer by @rafidini is a bit more elegant than mine.